# Why does the vlookup "????" is giving any word with four letters as output instead of perfect match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | ???? |
| Darcey | Jack |
| ???? | Magic |

> =VLOOKUP(b2,a:a,1,False)

Now, it matches Jack. But, in this case, if it can match with "????" in the first column, it should match with it. If there's not a perfect match, give #N/A.

How to deal with this? I don't want to use TRUE instead of FALSE as it can then hamper my other results.

Comment: It's doing a wildcard search. [See the docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-wildcard-characters-in-searches-ef94362e-9999-4350-ad74-4d2371110adb)

Comment: Escape the question marks.

Comment: Looking up an actual `?` requires you to tell Excel you're not looking for a wildcard (which `?` is to Excel in a lookup formula). To do so you need to add `"~"&` prior to the `?`. Since you use 4 `?`'s you'd have to add the tilde sign in front of each question mark to match it. In other words: avoid using the question mark at all as data.

Comment: @P.b Thanks It worked!